# How to capture EF exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to capture the error from entity framework.

So i have the below code

```
 return await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

if something goes wrong in the above code i want it to be captured as a warning in database, but as of now it is automatically saving in the database as error which has to be warning actually.

below is the error that i get

> An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context
>   type 'ValuationsReporting.Models.ValuationsReportingContext'. 
>   System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'TemplateTypeId' on
>   entity type 'ValuationFundTemplate' has a temporary value. Either set
>   a permanent value explicitly or ensure that the database is configured
>   to generate values for this property.     at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.CommandBatchPreparer.Validate(ModificationCommand
>   modificationCommand)     at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.CommandBatchPreparer.BatchCommands(IReadOnlyList`1
>   entries)+MoveNext()     at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(DbContext
>   _, ValueTuple`2 parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)     at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4
>   operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)     at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4
>   operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)     at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IReadOnlyList`1
>   entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)     at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean
>   acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)     at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean
>   acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> System.InvalidOperationException
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update

I tried using try catch but as soon as it goes to that line the error is logged in database.

Actual code :

```
try
                {
                    foreach (var template in snapshotDto.SnapshopFundTemplateDtos)
                    {
                        if (template.FundId != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var fundId in template.FundId)
                            {
                                var tempTemplate = allFundTemplates.Where(x => x.ValuationId == valuation.Id && x.FundId == fundId && x.TemplateTypeId == template.TemplateTypeId).FirstOrDefault();

                                //var tempTemplate = await _valuationFundTemplateRepository.GetOne(valuation.Id, fundId, template.TemplateTypeId, true, cancellationToken);
                                if (tempTemplate == null)
                                {
                                    tempTemplate = new ValuationFundTemplate();
                                    tempTemplate.CreatedBy = _userRepository.claimsPrincipal.Identity.Name;
                                    tempTemplate.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
                                    isTemplateUpdate = false;
                                }
                                //tempTemplate.IsDeleted = false;
                                //if (template.IsDeleted)
                                //{
                                //     _valuationFundTemplateRepository.Delete(tempTemplate);
                                //}
                                //else
                                //{
                                //tempTemplate.IsDeleted = template.IsDeleted;

                                tempTemplate.IsDeleted = false;
                                tempTemplate.IsDefaultFundTemplate = template.IsDefault;
                                tempTemplate.FundId = fundId;
                                tempTemplate.ValuationId = valuation.Id;
                                tempTemplate.TemplateTypeId = 0;
                                tempTemplate.TemplateId = template.TemplateId;
                                tempTemplate.ModifiedBy = _userRepository.claimsPrincipal.Identity.Name;
                                tempTemplate.ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
                                tempTemplates.Add(tempTemplate);
                                if (isTemplateUpdate)
                                {
                                    _valuationFundTemplateRepository.Update(tempTemplate);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    await _valuationFundTemplateRepository.Insert(tempTemplate, cancellationToken);
                                }
                                //  }

                                await _valuationFundTemplateRepository.SaveAsync(cancellationToken);//here is where the error occurs which i dont want to capture in database.
                                if (!isTemplateUpdate)
                                    valuation.ValuationFundTemplate.Add(tempTemplate);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    var z = e.Message;
                }



public virtual async Task<int> SaveAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            return await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
```

Comment: @PrashantPimpale i already tried using try catch but still the error is logged in the database

Comment: Unable to undestand - `error is logged in the database`? Can you explain?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale i tried the below code  try
            {
                
                return await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                var z1 = e.Message;
                return 0;
            } still it gets logged as error in database before it comes to catch block

Answer (score 2):

Agreed with the @PrashantPimpale you can simply use `try catch`.

But for the advanced approach, I would suggest you can use a Global Error Handling Middleware.
Through which you can capture any error occurred in the whole `dotnet` API/Application.

Just and Elaboration below:

```
// Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
    public static class ErrorHandlingMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseErrorHandlingMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();
        }
    }
```

Then add  `app.UseErrorHandlingMiddleware();` in the Startup's `Configure()` method.

You have to first create a `ErrorHandlingMiddleware` class.

```
 public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(httpContext);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex);
            }
        }

        private static async Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
        {
          // Implement how you want to handle the error.
        }
}
```

Comment: logging of error is already happening in the database . But i dont want 1 particular error to be logged in database.

Comment: can you please share your code as well. Will be much helpful.

Comment: I guess you have to also add try-catch in your SaveAsync method & then throw the error in Exception block.

Comment: FYI: Error is generating because you're not setting the updated entity to a Modified state. entity.Entry(updatedUser).State = EntityState.Modified;

Comment: i am aware of how this error is generating. I actually tried putting try catch in save async methd as well but still the error gets logged in the database before that.

Comment: did you try making the Update method async?

Comment: yes i did. What basically i want to do is that . I want to turn off all errors from entity framework to be logged

Comment: try this:             catch(Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.StackTrace.Contains("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore"))
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    // log the error 
                }
            }

Comment: even if i do that before it enters into the catch the error will be logged into the database.

Comment: I have this same issue. To clarify what the OP is saying is that EF Core ITSELF is emitting an Error log entry for this AND throwing a DbUpdateException. So even if you catch the exception then the error log entry still gets emitted. Its quite odd! I've not yet found a way to disable this internal logging in EF Core.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from my comment on the other answer - I have found a solution to this.

There are two things not immediately clear here, so to clarify:

1. There are legitimate reasons for wanting to suppress some DB errors and treat them as warnings (for instance) e.g. custom triggers checking data integrity
2. This is NOTHING to do with capturing an exception coming from EF Core, EF Core is DIRECTLY emitting error log lines for DbUpdateExceptions AS WELL AS throwing that exception to be caught by the application

So the solution here is to configure EF Core to change its behaviour and log failures to save changes as warnings instead of errors (could suppress completely - but I'm playing safe). I haven't found actual documentation on this, but with some experimentation have found configuring your context like this works correctly:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnConfiguring(builder);

    builder
        .ConfigureWarnings(x => x
            .Log(
                (CoreEventId.SaveChangesFailed, LogLevel.Warning)
            )
        );
}
```